Dianoga errors in image processing Error
We have Sitecore 10.2, and installed Dianoga for image optimize with latest version. after installing the required file and deployed into the server.
After restart the site we are not getting the optmized image and getting error in Dignoga logs.
ERROR Dianoga: Unable to optimize {Image path} due to a processing error! It will be unchanged.

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: "~\Dianoga Tools\PNGOptimizer\PNGOptimizerCL.exe -file "C:\windows\TEMP\tmp5A88.png"" took longer than 60000ms to run, which is a failure. Output: 

Optimizing tmp5A88.png 
Source: Dianoga
   at Dianoga.Optimizers.CommandLineToolOptimizer.ExecuteProcess(String arguments)
   at Dianoga.Optimizers.CommandLineToolOptimizer.ProcessOptimizer(OptimizerArgs args)
   at Dianoga.Optimizers.OptimizerProcessor.Process(OptimizerArgs args)

And
Getting all the image "cannot be optimized due to media type or path exlusion.
ERROR Dianoga:Unable to optimize /Project/{project Name]/assets/home/[image name] due to a processing error !It will be unchanged
Exception:System.InvalidOperationException
Message:"C:\inetpub\wwroot\[Project Nmae]\App_Data\Dianoga Tools\mozjpeg\cjpeg.exe -quality 80 -outfile "C:\Windows\TEMP\tmp449B.tmp" "C:\Windows\TEMP449A.tmp"" could not be started because an error occurred.see the inner exception for details.
Source:Dianoga
   
   at Dianoga.Optimizers.CommandLineToolOptimizer.ExecuteProcess(string arguments)
at Dianoga.Optimizers.CommandLineToolOptimizer.ProcessOptimizer(OptimizerArgs  args)
at Dianoga.Optimizers.OptimizerProcessor.Process(OptimizerArgs  args)

Nested Exception

Exception:System.ComponentModel.Win32 Exception
Message:The system cannot find the path specified
Source:System
at system.Diagnostics.process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartINfo startInfo)
at Dianoga.Optimizers.CommandLineToolOptimizer.ExecuteProcess(string arguments)


Can you check the media cache folder path on the server where you installed Dianoga using showconfig...Then clear that media cache folder...

App_Data/MediaCache -> this is path , here media file is stored but still same size image before dianoga and after

did you enabled the z.01.Dianoga.NextGenFormats.WebP.config config?

No, I did not enabled it. After installing the Nuget for Dianoga getting config file. deployed default files

is it possible to connect on slack?

yeah sure. can i get the link

are you on sitecore slack?

@ckhanna add the logs in description

I have posted my answer below. Let me know in case you face any issues.

While configuring Dianoga, you need to copy the Dianoga Tools folder to the App_Data folder of  your website.
Since these are exe files, they may be blocked when you download them. Therefore you can unblock the exe file by right clicking the file, checking the Unblock checkbox and clicking Apply as shown below.

Note: Check the Unblock checkbox for each of the exe files located under the Dianoga Tools folder.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.

Thanks this is working!!
